# How to verify server hostname

Tags: delphi, ssl, openssl, certificate, indy

I'm using Indy `TIdHTTP` (shipped with XE2) and the OpenSSL library DLLs V1.0.1m to verify a certificate when connecting over HTTPS. I have implemented an event handler for the `OnVerifyPeer` event of the `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` component.

```
function TForm1.IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1VerifyPeer(Certificate: TIdX509;
  AOk: Boolean; ADepth, AError: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  (...)
end;
```

> According to RFC 2818, chapter 3.1., if the hostname is available to
>   the client, the client MUST check it against the server's identity as
>   presented in the server's Certificate message, in order to prevent
>   man-in-the-middle attacks.

Now I have a problem to verify the hostname of the server certificate:

Although a wildcard is present in the Common Name (CN)
field in the Subject field within the server certificate (*.google.com),
the parameter `Certificate.Subject.OneLine` of the `OnVerifyPeer` event
returns the CN without any wildcard (i.e. google.com instead of *.google.com).

> As stated in RFC 2818, chapter 3.1. the wildcard character * is used
>   to match any single domain name component or component fragment.

1. Can anyone confirm that the wildcard character is removed by Indy or the OpenSSL libraries, although it is necessary to verify the hostname?
2. Has anyone an idea to verify the hostname under these circumstances?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks for reading.

Comment: The certificate data is provided by OpenSSL itself. Indy's `TIdX509` class simply wraps a `PX509` handle provided by OpenSSL inside of Indy's verification callback function. `TIdX509` does not mess around with the certificate data, it presents it as-is.  The `Subject` property wraps a `PX509_NAME` handle from OpenSSL's `X509_get_subject_name()` function, and the `OneLine` property returns whatever value OpenSSL's `X509_NAME_oneline()` function returns. So it is OpenSSL itself that is stripping the wildcard.

Comment: That being said, OpenSSL does have `X509_check_host()` and `certificate_host_name_override()` functions. You can pass them the original `PX509` handle (the `TIdX509.FX509` member - you would have to use an accessor class to reach it though) and the hostname you connected to.

Comment: Thank you Remy for the quick response. I will try that tomorrow and let you know about my results.

Comment: Now i had some time do deal with the problem, but what do you mean with an "accessor class" exactly?
In my opinion, a derived class has no use, because I can't force Indy to access it.

Comment: An *accessor class* is a common technique in Delphi to access the `protected` members of a target class that is declared in another unit. Simply derive a new class from the target class in the unit that needs access. The derived class has access to its ancestor's `protected` members, and the derived class's unit has access to the derived class's members, including inherited `protected` members. Thus, the target class's `protected` members can be accessed  in the derived class's unit...

Comment: ... You simply type-cast an object pointer of the target class into the derived class to access its `protected` members. The derived class does not introduce any new data members, and thus has the same size and layout as the target class. For example, in this situation: `type TIdX509Access = class(TIdX509) end; var HostName: AnsiString; HostName := ...; if x509_check_host(TIdX509Access(Certificate).FX509, PAnsiChar(HostName), Length(HostName), 0, nil) = 1 then ...`

Comment: Indy avoids the use of `private` members in most of its classes, declaring them as `protected` instead, specifically to allow the use of accessor classes when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I have to stick to XE2-Indy and OpenSSL V1.0.1m due to internal specifications.

To verify the hostname against the Subject CN and Subject Alternate Names, I've done the following (using the approach [cURL's implementation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Hostname_validation)):

**1. At application startup, I'm trying once to extend the access to methods within the Indy crypto library.**

```
function ExtendIndyCryptoLibrary(): Boolean;
var
  hIdCrypto: HMODULE;
begin
  Result := False;

  // Try to get handle to Indy used crypto library
  if not IdSSLOpenSSL.LoadOpenSSLLibrary() then
    Exit;
  hIdCrypto := IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders.GetCryptLibHandle();
  if hIdCrypto = 0 then
    Exit();

  // Try to get exported methods that are needed additionally
  @X509_get_ext_d2i := GetProcAddress(hIdCrypto, 'X509_get_ext_d2i');

  Result := Assigned(X509_get_ext_d2i);
end;
```

**2. The follwing class helps me to access and verify the SAN and CN.**

```
type
  THostnameValidationResult = (hvrMatchNotFound, hvrNoSANPresent, hvrMatchFound);
var
  X509_get_ext_d2i: function(a: PX509; nid: TIdC_INT; var pcrit: PIdC_INT; var pidx: PIdC_INT): PSTACK_OF_GENERAL_NAME; cdecl = nil;
type
  TIdX509Access = class(TIdX509)
  protected
    function Hostmatch(Hostname, Pattern: String): Boolean;
    function MatchesSAN(Hostname: String): THostnameValidationResult;
    function MatchesCN(Certificate: TIdX509; Hostname: String): THostnameValidationResult;
  public
    function ValidateHostname(Certificate: TIdX509; Hostname: String): THostnameValidationResult;
  end;

implementation

{ TIdX509Access }

function TIdX509Access.Hostmatch(Hostname, Pattern: String): Boolean;
begin
  // Match hostname against pattern using RFC, CA/Browser Forum, ...
  // (...)
end;

function TIdX509Access.MatchesSAN(Hostname: String): THostnameValidationResult;
var
  pcrit, pidx: PIdC_INT;
  psan_names: PSTACK_OF_GENERAL_NAME;
  san_names_nb: Integer;
  pcurrent_name: PGENERAL_NAME;
  i: Integer;
  DnsName: String;
begin
  Result := hvrMatchNotFound;

  // Try to extract the names within the SAN extension from the certificate
  pcrit := nil;
  pidx := nil;
  psan_names := X509_get_ext_d2i(FX509, NID_subject_alt_name, pcrit, pidx);
  // Check if SAN is present
  if psan_names <> nil then
  begin
    san_names_nb := sk_num(PSTACK(psan_names));
    // Check each name within the extension
    for i := 0 to san_names_nb-1 do
    begin
      pcurrent_name := PGENERAL_NAME( sk_value(PSTACK(psan_names), i) );
      if pcurrent_name._type = GEN_DNS then
      begin
        // Current name is a DNS name, let's check it
        DnsName := String(pcurrent_name.d.dNSName.data);
        // Compare expected hostname with the DNS name
        if Hostmatch(Hostname, DnsName) then
        begin
          Result := hvrMatchFound;
          Break;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end
  else
    Result := hvrNoSANPresent;
  // Clean up
  sk_free(PSTACK(psan_names));
end;

function TIdX509Access.MatchesCN(Certificate: TIdX509;
  Hostname: String): THostnameValidationResult;
var
  TempList: TStringList;
  Cn: String;
begin
  Result := hvrMatchNotFound;

  // Extract CN from Subject
  TempList := TStringList.Create();
  TempList.Delimiter := '/';
  TempList.DelimitedText := Certificate.Subject.OneLine;
  Cn := Trim(TempList.Values['CN']);
  FreeAndNil(TempList);

  // Compare expected hostname with the CN
  if Hostmatch(Hostname, Cn) then
    Result := hvrMatchFound;
end;

function TIdX509Access.ValidateHostname(Certificate: TIdX509;
  Hostname: String): THostnameValidationResult;
begin
  // First try the Subject Alternative Names extension
  Result := MatchesSAN(Hostname);
  if Result = hvrNoSANPresent then
  begin
    // Extension was not found: try the Common Name
    Result := MatchesCN(Certificate, Hostname);
  end;
end;
```

**3. In the OnVerifyPeer event of the TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL component, the class can be used as follows:**

```
function TForm1.IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1VerifyPeer(Certificate: TIdX509;
  AOk: Boolean; ADepth, AError: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  // (...)
    Result := TIdX509Access(Certificate).ValidateHostname(Certificate, IdHttp1.URL.Host) = hvrMatchFound;
  // (...)
end;
```

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Am I messing up Indy internally by using this approach?
So far I had no problems. I just want to prevent that other people are doing something wrong by using this implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. Although I've accepted the answer, I'd still like to receive a response from Remy.

Comment: Be care with a domain in the `CN`, which is quite common. That is, you will experience `CN=example.com`. In this case, `example.com` is a ***domain***, and not a ***server name***. You should not interpret it to mean host `example.com`, or all hosts in the domain `*.example.com`. Server names go in `Subject Alternate Name (SAN)`.

Answer (score 3):

> Can anyone confirm that the wildcard character is removed by Indy or the OpenSSL libraries, although it is necessary to verify the hostname?

No, OpenSSL does not remove it.

I don't know about the Indy library.

---

> Can anyone confirm that the wildcard character is removed by Indy or the OpenSSL libraries, although it is necessary to verify the hostname?

I'm citing this twice for a reason :) Placing server names in the *Common Name* (CN) is deprecated by both the IETF and CA/B Forums (what the browsers follow).

What you are probably experiencing is something like `CN=example.com`. In this case, `example.com` ***is not*** a server name; rather it ***is*** a domain. So you ***should not*** assume it means to match `*.example.com`.

And if a server answers at `https://example.com`, you should only accept the certificate if the *Subject Alternate Name* includes `example.com` because domains are listed in the CN by the public CAs. Public CAs place DNS names in the SAN because they follow the CA/B Forums.

---

> Has anyone an idea to verify the hostname under these circumstances?

OpenSSL prior to 1.1.0 did *not* perform hostname matching. The developer had to do it. OpenSSL 1.1.0 and above has the functionality built in. See [`X509_check_host(3)`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/X509_check_host.html) and friends.

To match a hostname, you should gather all the names from ***both*** the *Common Name (CN)* and the *Subject Alternate Name (SAN)*. Then, its usually as simple as a Regular Expression matching.

The IETF is fast-and-loose, and they allow a hostname to show up in either the CN or the SAN. The CA/B Forum and Browsers are more strict: if a hostname is in the CN, then it must also be present in the SAN (yes, it must be listed twice). Otherwise, the CA/B Forum and Browsers expect all hostnames in the SAN.

I believe OpenSSL and the CA/B Forums only allow a wildcard in the leftmost label. I believe the IETF allows wildcards to show up anywhere.

If you want to see sample code, then check out cURL's implementation. cURL uses OpenSSL, but does not depend on 1.1.0's [`X509_check_host(3)`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/X509_check_host.html) and friends. cURL has its own implementation.

---

A quick warning. Hostname matching is a black art. For example....

The IETF allows matching to a Global Top Level Domain (gTLD) like `*.com` or `*.net`; and Country Top Level Domain (ccTLD) like `*.uk` or `*.us`. I consider this an attack because I know there is no single CA that can claim to "own" or "certify" a gTLD. If I experience one of those certs in the wild, then I reject it.

The CA/B Forums do not allow wildcarding gTLDs or ccTLDs. The browsers attempt to avoid it by using [Public Suffix List](https://publicsuffix.org/) (PSL). Things have only gotten worse with the vanity domains, like `*.google`.

There's another thing that browsers attempt to do with the PSL. They attempt to carve out administrative boundaries on subdomains. For example, Amazon owns all of amazon.com, but they delegate authority to subdomains, like example.amazon.com. So the PSL attempts to allow Amazon to control their domain `amazon.com`, but not your merchant related subdomain of `example.amazon.com`.

The IETF is attempting to tackle administrative boundaries in the [DBOUND Working Group](https://datatracker.ietf.org/wg/dbound/charter/). But things appear to be stalled in committee.

Comment: **Can anyone confirm that the wildcard character is removed by Indy or the OpenSSL libraries, although it is necessary to verify the hostname?** Although I was quite sure that the wildcard was stripped off in "Certificate.Subject.OnLine", this phenomenon has not occurred again (tested with https://www.youtube.com).